# Codeigniter is showing 404 Error in live website

Tags: codeigniter

i am trying to add a page into existing Codeigniter website. www.cryptolord.com
I have added the link in template.php file
i have made the page in view as sell.php
I have made the page in Controller as Sell.php

Still having 404 error. 
Please help to solve this issue.
Thanks

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Protect extends Public_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->lang->load('welcome');
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->set_title(sprintf(lang('core button sell'), $this->settings->site_name));
        $data            = $this->includes;
        $content_data    = array();
        $data['content'] = $this->load->view('sell', $content_data, TRUE);
        $this->load->view($this->template, $data);
    }
}
```

This is for sell.php in Views

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?> <div class="header-bg">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-7"> 
            <h3><?php echo lang('core button sell'); ?></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Consider adding code, details and symptoms of your problem. At the actual moment, we cannot do anything.

Comment: <?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Protect extends Public_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->lang->load('welcome');
    }

 function index()
 {
        $this->set_title(sprintf(lang('core button sell'), $this->settings->site_name));

        $data = $this->includes;

        $content_data = array(
        );

        $data['content'] = $this->load->view('sell', $content_data, TRUE);
  $this->load->view($this->template, $data);
 }

}

Comment: above code is for Sell.php in Controllers

Comment: This code is for sell.php in Views folder

<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>

<div class="header-bg">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-7">
      <h3><?php echo lang('core button sell'); ?></h3>
     </div>
    </div>

Comment: This is log file from my system

 404 Page Not Found: Themes/default
 404 Page Not Found: Sell/index
ERROR - 2017-12-18 09:12:47 --> 404 Page Not Found: Themes/default
ERROR - 2017-12-18 09:12:50 --> 404 Page Not Found: Sell/index
ERROR - 2017-12-18 09:16:27 --> 404 Page Not Found: Themes/default
ERROR - 2017-12-18 09:16:33 --> 404 Page Not Found: Sell/index
ERROR - 2017-12-18 09:16:36 --> 404 Page Not Found: Themes/default

Comment: Please don't add code in comments: it's nearly impossible to read. Instead, [edit] your question and add it there. If you select a block of code and press Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button it will get indented by four spaces and SO will treat it as code.

Comment: Yeah, I mean, edit your question. That's what I meant.

Comment: i have edited the code as you said. please have a look

Comment: @SyedHassanMujtabaZaidi , did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your Sell.php controller has a class inside it that is "Protect", and it should be "Sell".

So this line:

```
class Protect extends Public_Controller
```

Should be like this:

```
class Sell extends Public_Controller
```

You must have your own base controller named "Public_Controller", but if not you should also change that to "CI_Controller".